# Default Back button is not working when used react-native-google-place-autocomplete?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have just 2 scenes - one is home screen and another is for google autocomplete.

Here is my code.

```
<Router>
  <Scene title="Home"/>
  <Scene title="AutoComplete"/>
</Router>
...
// this is AutoComplete Component.
...
return (
 <GooglePlaceAutoComplete ... />
)
```

When I open this component then just click default back button without any autocomplete, it's not working at all on my iPhone device.

But All is good at Emulator.

What is the difference between Emulator and Real device?
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: It should be working properly on your real device if it's working on the simulator. Did you ran it on a different version of iOS?